# How to get a count of all the folders/directories in a git repository?

Tags: bash, git

I know I can use the following to count the number of files in a repo:

```
git ls-files | wc -l
```

I just wonder if there is a similar method to count all folders (including hidden and subfolders).

I have tried:

```
ls -d /mnt/c/Users/USERNAME/GIT/REPO/*/ |wc -l
```

but the above only lists the folders ignoring subfolders and hidden folders.

Comment: Try this:
ls -la /mnt/c/Users/USERNAME/GIT/REPO/*/ | wc -l

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe:

```
find /mnt/c/Users/USERNAME/GIT/REPO/ -type d | wc -l
```